# Dynamic Broadcast Receiver Not registering

Tags: android, dynamic, broadcastreceiver

I have registered broadcast receiver statically and it's working perfectly fine. But I have to register it dynamically as my activity is to receive data from a broadcast receiver.

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String TAG = "MyReceiver:";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)){
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            String packageName = intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
            Log.d(TAG, "Action: " + intent.getAction());
            Log.d(TAG, "The DATA Now: " + data);
            Log.d(TAG, "The Name Now: " + packageName);

            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("message", packageName);
            Log.d(TAG,"Starting list act");
            ctx.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MyReceiver receiver;
    IntentFilter intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        receiver = new MyReceiver();
        intent = new IntentFilter(); 
        intent.addAction("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED");
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, intent);
        Log.v("calling Dynamic Broadcast()", "MainActivity");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message1 = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        Log.v("Back From Rcver:", "added pkg is: " + message1);
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
01-19 11:48:36.372: V/calling Dynamic Broadcast()(3053): MainActivity
```

I am unable to get package_add logs from MyReceiver class once package is added. What I am doing wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: also add `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADD` action with IntentFilter

Comment: It didn't show logs within MyReceiver Class. Any idea why its so

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is not to forget about data scheme in the intent filter:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
filter.addDataScheme("package");
mContext.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: THIS IS the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal suggestion don't add dynamic broadcast receiver onReceive in broadcast file. Add it on first activity or main activity of your application. If you needed it only when your application is open. But if you need it always received response just added it on manifest file

### Register dynamic broadcast receiver on main activity

```
MyReceiver reciver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    reciver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(reciver, intentFilter);
}
```

### Unregister that broadcast receiver on activity stop or closed

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(reciver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple mistake you done at

```
intent.addAction("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED");
```

you have registered only package removed action in `IntentFilter`

its something like this...

```
intent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
intent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
```

EDIT:

still there is typo mistake in your code.

```
intent.addAction("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADD");
```

should be

```
intent.addAction("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"); // last two characters ED are missing
```

use predifined Constant Strings of Intent to avoid typo mistake...

```
intent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
```

Comment: This is right, also remember to use Local Broadcasts as far as it is possible, this way the broadcasts will have just the scope of your application.

Comment: @NKN use of LocalBroadcastManager is a bit different... Receivers registered through this Manager will receive Intents only when that particular Broadcast is sent through LocalBroadcastManager...

Comment: @GopalRao: It not working still. That was typo mistake while posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the default category to you IntentFilter:

```
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```